# DateTime.Parse works in c# console app but not asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have written a C# console application that after all of it's processing outputs a `DateTime` to disk. It does this like so:

`writer.WriteLine(myDateTime)`.

This same console appication has no problems with using the following to read this `DateTime` back:

`DateTime.Parse(reader.ReadLine())`

However, upon attempting to use the following code in my separate `Asp.Net` program I recieve an error saying that my `string` is not a valid `DateTime` which is odd to say the least.

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\InformerReports\Archive\ReliabilityData\StartTime.hist");
string dateString = reader.ReadLine();
return DateTime.Parse(dateString);
```

I have checked and the string it is reading in is `10/25/2016 12:00:00 AM`.
 I have also attempted to use `return DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",null)` but this returns the same error.

I can't seem to fathom why identical code performed on the same file works in one case and not the other. I'd appreciate some help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess the culture of the server is different from the machine you are testing from.

The correct format you have to use seems to be:

```
return DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", null)
//                                      10/25/2016 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: ahh... That would make sense. I hadn't considered that my server is hosted in America, hence why I was expecting `dd/mm/yyyy` and didn't double check my string!

Comment: It doesn't matter *where* it is hosted. It does matter what culture the user has who is running that code. Depending on your site the culture may vary across users. It is always best to specify the format if you know it.

Comment: The server is set to America for now, but when it enters production it will be set to UK, looks like I need to change that.

Answer (score 1):

As an add-on to the previous answers.
To avoid the differing cultures across clients you can set the site culture in the global.asax files Application_BeginRequest method like below:

```
Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
```

This will force the above specified culture for each user accessing the site.

I am not sure if there are drawbacks to doing it this way, but this solved my issue in the past.